# IF statement not skipping TempDB when Looping through Databases with sp_MSForEachDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tempdb

[SQL Server 2012 SP2 EE]

Why does the following script gives me an error relating to tempdb?

```
    exec sp_MSForEachDB '
    IF ( (select database_id from sys.databases where name = ''?'') > 4)
    BEGIN 
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::? TO [sa];
    ALTER DATABASE [?] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
    END'
```

Here is the error I get:

```
  Msg 5058, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
  Option 'RECOVERY' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'.
```

It does the job it's supposed to do. But I am unable to think of a reason for the error. I know that the tempdb's databaseID is 2, then at least it should not try to set the option for tempdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE TO READERS: Please read the entire question, including the example code (i.e. not just the title). This question is *not* about how to best cycle through databases, nor is it about why does [tempdb] receive this error. The O.P. is already trying to avoid executing the `ALTER` statements on all system databases (well, the 4 visible ones) and is asking why the IF statement that should be skipping [tempdb] does not appear to be skipping it.**

> Why does the following script gives me an error relating to tempdb?

The reason is that the `IF` statement only affects what happens when the code is actually running, but SQL Server still has to parse and compile the batch prior to executing it. Parse errors are ones related to syntax, such as making sure that SQL statements are properly formed and that variables have been properly declared:

```sql
-- parse the following by hitting Control-F5 or clicking the check mark in SSMS
SELECT @Bob;
```

gets the following error:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@Bob".
```

And the following:

```sql
-- parse the following by hitting Control-F5 or clicking the check mark in SSMS
CREATE TABLE b
```

gets the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'b'.
```

If the batch parses successfully, then it is compiled, at which time things like permissions are checked and some other checks are performed.

```sql
-- parse the following by hitting Control-F5 or clicking the check mark in SSMS
IF (1 = 0)
BEGIN 
  ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[tempdb] TO [sa];
  ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
END;
```

The above SQL is properly formed so the batch parses successfully. Now try to execute the above SQL by hitting **F5** or **Control-E** or the **! Execute** button, etc.

This time you get the following error:

```
Msg 5058, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Option 'RECOVERY' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'.
```

even though the `IF (1 = 0)` ensures that the code will never run. This means that you are running into a compilation error. You can get around these types of errors by moving the offending code into a subprocess via an `EXEC` call.

Execute the following and it will complete successfully since what is inside of the `EXEC()` is not parsed or compiled until that statement is executed at runtime.

```sql
IF (1 = 0)
BEGIN
  EXEC('
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[tempdb] TO [sa];
    ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
  ');
END;
```

---

**To summarize:**
First, consider that `sp_MSForEachDB` cycles through the databases and executes your passed-in SQL after replacing the `?` with the current database name. So when the cursor inside of `sp_MSForEachDB` gets to `[tempdb]`, it effectively does the following:

```sql
IF ( (select database_id from sys.databases where name = ''tempdb'') > 4)
BEGIN 
  ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::tempdb TO [sa];
  ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
END
```

Second, there are several steps that SQL Server takes when you execute a query batch:

1. Parse
2. Compile
3. Actual Execution

It is important to understand that these are separate steps and can generate errors before proceeding to the next step (and hence cancel further processing before going on to that next step). In the case here, the error is happening in Step 2 -- Compile -- as proven in the 2nd to last example above (the first one to start with `IF (1 = 0)`). The `IF (1 = 0)` prevents the code inside of the `BEGIN...END` block from ever running, yet the error still occurs. Hence the error is not happening due to an actual attempt to run the two `ALTER` statements.

The reason that wrapping the `ALTER` statements inside of the `EXEC()` function works is because SQL Server will not parse and compile what is inside of the `EXEC()` until the `EXEC()` is actually running. At that point, the `IF ( (select database_id from sys.databases where name = ''?'') > 4)` statement will be allowed to run since the batch won't fail during Compilation and will make it to Execution, and the `IF` statement *will* skip over `[tempdb]` and the "Option 'RECOVERY' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'" error will not occur.

Comment: My question is - Why is "if" statement allowing tempdb's ID (that is, 2) to be sent to the if statement block if it doesn't satisfy the condition of being greater than 4.

Comment: @GaganLamba I understand your question and answered it very specifically. Did you run my examples? As I stated in the answer, this is a compile-time, not run-time, error. Hence neither the `IF` statement nor any other SQL statements (including the two `ALTER`s) are being executed at this point. The `IF` statement is _not_ allowing tempdb's ID to be sent to what is inside the `BEGIN` / `END` block, and the code is not even running the `ALTER` statements at this point. The error is being thrown by SQL Server as it is validating the SQL _before_ executing it. I added a summary section to the end.

Answer (score 3):

> Msg 5058, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>     Option 'RECOVERY' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'.
>
> It does the job it's supposed to do. But I am unable to think of a
>   reason for the error.

First of all there is no need to use `ms_foreachdb` its undocumented and way bad you can loop in using simple cursor. Regarding error you are trying to change recovery model of all database `including tempdb` but you cannot change recovery model of tempdb neither you can perform any backup operation on it that is why you got this error message. This is not allowed by Microsoft. Please read more about [operations you can do on tempdb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I get your point that ms_foreachdb is undocumented and I should not use it. I also understand that tempdb is not supposed to be backedup or change recovery option. But my question is still unanswered as to why SQL server is trying to change the option for TEMPDB? TEMPDB's ID, which is 2,  wasn't even returned.

Comment: @GaganLamba SQL Server is not actually trying to change the option for TEMPDB. The `ALTER` statements are merely being _validated_, not executed. I provide details in my [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104500/30859).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that you cant change the recovery option for tempdb, You **dont need a loop** for what you are doing :

Run in SSMS by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
select 'alter authorization on database::' + quotename(name) + ' to [sa];' + char(10) + 'alter database ' + quotename(name) + ' set recovery simple;'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 4
    and state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```